# how to catch reponse from server from nested json in android

Tags: c#, php, android, asp.net, .net

i am trying to catch response in my volley library from this link

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "1": {
                "del_id": "1",
                "image1": "",
                "image2": "",
                "image3": "",
                "moving_item": "gvxx",
                "pick_up": "Luton, UK",
                "drop_off": "Brasília - Brasilia, Federal District, Brazil",
                "lat_pickup": "51.8786707",
                "long_pickup": "-0.4200255000000001",
                "lat_dropoff": "-15.7942287",
                "long_dropoff": "-47.882165799999996",
                "distance": "5459",
                "add_type": "personal",
                "date": "23-02-2018",
                "totalbid": "0",
                "current_bid": null
            },
            "2": {
                "del_id": "2",
                "image1": "47cdb3b7deb1572db979bd7d5e940364.jpg",
                "image2": "23cd1ee8a710ac4b88625178538e3537.jpeg",
                "image3": "",
                "moving_item": "hshaj",
                "pick_up": "Lutz, FL, USA",
                "drop_off": "Bradenton, FL, USA",
                "lat_pickup": "28.151124299999996",
                "long_pickup": "-82.4614831",
                "lat_dropoff": "27.498927799999997",
                "long_dropoff": "-82.5748194",
                "distance": "45",
                "add_type": "personal",
                "date": "02-12-2018",
                "totalbid": "0",
                "current_bid": null
            }]
```

but it did not catches and through exception i am using this code to catch reponse in my android applciation.

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray c1 = obj.getJSONArray("data");
                            //JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < c1.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject searchlist = c1.getJSONObject(i);
                                searchmodel.add(new SearchModel(
                                        searchlist.optString("moving_item"),
                                        searchlist.optString("pick_up"),
                                        searchlist.optString("drop_off"),
                                        searchlist.optDouble("distance"),
                                        searchlist.optInt("totalbid"),
                                        searchlist.optInt("current_bid"),
                                        searchlist.optString("date"),
                                        searchlist.optString("image1")

                                ));
                            }
```

please help me to resolve my issue i am trying my best to resolve this issue i am very thankfull if anyone take me out from this thank you

Comment: There is two main issue with your code.
1) Your json is invalid
2) You are trying to parse JsonObject whereas your response is JsonArray.

Comment: will you give me anycode example to reolve this issue @ku

Comment: bro it gave me JSONexception @Aj27

Comment: Post your proper json. And you can check a json is valid or not [here](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @RanaAbdulWajid first of all paste your whole json so we know how to parse it on seeing your json first of all start parsing with jsonArray.

Comment: @Kunu i paste my json response it says valid json please help to catch this response

Answer (score 0):

Hey man first of all this is not the place to get this type of logic you have to search more untill you get it but as thinking it your starting in android so I'm providing you how to parse your json verify the answer if its right to help others I've tried it and its working fine hope this help you:

```
try {

            JSONArray jsonRootArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i=0;i<jsonRootArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonRootArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                for (int j=1;j<=jsonObject1.length();j++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject(j+"");
                    String del_id = jsonObject2.getString("del_id");
                    Log.e("id",del_id);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And also one tip

## before start just check your json on http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ if its invalid and also from that you'll get the idea how to parse it.

Comment: thanks bro for your precious time i will definatly tried this